# How to show only directories in JTree?

Tags: java, jtree

I am trying to show only directories in JTree but my below code is showing is directories and files both .can anyone please help me to show only directories.

```
//Class1


public class FileBrowser implements Runnable {

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;

    private JTree tree;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        File fileRoot = new File("C:\\JDeveloper\\Testing");
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new FileNodes(fileRoot));
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

        tree = new JTree(treeModel);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
                   private Icon loadIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
                              private Icon saveIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
               @Override
               public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,
                                           Object value,
                                           boolean bSelected,
                                           boolean bExpanded,
                                           boolean bLeaf,
                                           int iRow,
                                           boolean bHasFocus ) {
                   Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                           bSelected, bExpanded, bLeaf, iRow, bHasFocus);

                   return c;
               }
           });
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        CreateChildNode ccn = new CreateChildNode(fileRoot, root);
        new Thread(ccn).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FileBrowser());
    }
}

//Class 2
class CreateChildNode implements Runnable {

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    private File fileRoot;

    public CreateChildNode(File fileRoot, DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
        this.fileRoot = fileRoot;
        this.root = root;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        createChildren(fileRoot, root);
    }

    private void createChildren(File fileRoot,
                                DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {

        File[] files = fileRoot.listFiles();
                       for (File child : files) {
                           System.out.println("Path :" +child.getName());
                           DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode =
                               new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new FileNodes(child));
                           System.out.println("Child Node :" +childNode);
                           System.out.println("File :" +child.getAbsoluteFile());
                           root.add(childNode);  
                       if (child.isDirectory() ) {
                           createChildren(child, childNode);
                   }
        }                  
    }

}

class FileNodes {

    private File file;

    public FileNodes(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    public File getFile() {
            return file;
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String name = file.getName();
        if (name.equals("")) {
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check for a directory before add to the tree

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by keshan on 7/26/2016.
 */
public class FileBrowser implements Runnable {

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;

    private JTree tree;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        File fileRoot = new File("C:");
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new FileNodes(fileRoot));
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

        tree = new JTree(treeModel);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
            private Icon loadIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
            private Icon saveIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
            @Override
            public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent( JTree tree,
                                                           Object value,
                                                           boolean bSelected,
                                                           boolean bExpanded,
                                                           boolean bLeaf,
                                                           int iRow,
                                                           boolean bHasFocus ) {
                Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                        bSelected, bExpanded, false, iRow, bHasFocus);

                return c;
            }
        });
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        CreateChildNode ccn = new CreateChildNode(fileRoot, root);
        new Thread(ccn).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FileBrowser());
    }
}

class CreateChildNode implements Runnable {

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    private File fileRoot;

    public CreateChildNode(File fileRoot, DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
        this.fileRoot = fileRoot;
        this.root = root;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        createChildren(fileRoot, root);
    }

    private void createChildren(File fileRoot, DefaultMutableTreeNode root)
    {
        File[] files = fileRoot.listFiles();
        if ( files != null )
        {
            for( File child : files )
            {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( new FileNodes( child ) );
                if( child.isDirectory() )
                {
                    root.add( childNode );
                    createChildren( child, childNode );
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

class FileNodes {

    private File file;

    public FileNodes(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String name = file.getName();
        if (name.equals("")) {
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot - Only Directories]

Comment: Thanks for the solution i have tried both solution but it is showing the Directory with only files as leaf node.

Comment: It is showing the directory containing only files as a leaf node . Please help me with the solution so that only folders are seen in JTree and no files.

Comment: @user6577633 I have update the code segment to filter out the files.

Comment: can u please merge in my code and show as i m new in Java and unable to merge please help wer to insert your code.

Comment: @user6577633 I have added complete code block. You can try that one.

Comment: @user6577633 I have modify the logic in createChildren() method and one parameter in the super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(). Please compare with your existing code with this complete code to identify the changes. BTW feel free to accept the answer if it really resolve your question.

Comment: can u add in the code treeselectionlistner so that wen i click on the JTree i get the exact path of that folder .

Comment: and others : Please help to add tree selectionlistner in the above code so i can get the full path ofthe folder i select from JTree .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in java as below

```
File file=new File("PATH_TO_FILE");

String directories[]=file.list(new FilenameFilter()
{
  public boolean accept(File yourFile, String name) {
    return new File(yourFile, name).isDirectory();
  }

}
```

Comment: @keshan de silva : can u tell me wat changes you have made in my file.and thanks for the solution it worked.

Comment: @user6577633 Are you asking me or keshan :)

Comment: @keshan. : I am asking you

Comment: @keshan and others : Please help to add tree selectionlistner in the above code so i can get the full path ofthe folder i select from JTree .

Comment: @user6577633 If you have more question ask again. You already choose  right answer.